# How can I do the correct working of mouseEnter event with form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method, like that:

```
private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)sender;
            form1.Opacity = 1;
        }

private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)sender;
            form1.Opacity = .5;
        }
```

But when my mouse enters other form elements like buttons and other, the second method fires and the first one becomes inactive

I want the first method to work even when hovering over buttons and other form elements and gets inactive only when the mouse leave the form

I tried to give all form elements a subscription to the mouse hover event, but obviously this did not help (I did it out of desperation)

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279472 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811181